File is added to .gitignore but is still shown in "Working directory changes"
I'm working with files with a specific filename, something like:
Site/Product Client/Modules/Product.Customer.Client.dll

(The words "Product" and "Customer" are replaced by corresponding names)
Right-clicking in Git-Extensions on such a file gives me the opportunity to add this file to .gitignore, this seems not to work: the file is still visible.
Next to that, also quite some regular expressions seem not to work:
/Site/**/Product.*.dll (amongst others)

I have the impression that Git has troubles working with spaces in its directory structures in .gitignore.
I'm working with Git Extensions version 4.2.1.17611, based on Git version git version 2.45.1.windows.1 (commandline git version).
Does anybody have an idea?

Well, when a file is added to .gitignore it should not be shown anymore in the "Wroking directory changes" list, isn't it?

"Working directory changes"? Does that imply that the file is already tracked? .gitignore matters only for files that are untracked.

@j6t: What I mean is the following: when this repository was started, the developer did not care about any DLL files in the list of tracked files. I do care about them and I wish not to see those files anymore (nor do I still want to track them). Therefore I want to add them to some "blacklist", containing a list of files which are not to be tracked anymore. I believed .gitignore being such a "blacklist", or am I mistaking here?

@Dominique Your comment implies that the file is already tracked (has been committed). Now you are back at "how to ignore changes to a committed file". There are plenty of answers here on SO. (Spoiler: you can't unless you commit the removal of the file.)

@evolutionxbox: although it might be the same situation, it's not entirely the same thing as I didn't realise the files were tracked. Once I realised this, I knew what to do (as explained in my own answer).

Does it matter whether you realised they were or not? The solution seems to be the same.

@evolutionxbox: I believe it matters: when you don't realise something, you won't use it as a search criterion :-)

As the file was already tracked by the previous developer, first I needed to stop that tracking, only once this is done I can add it to .gitignore.
In order to stop the tracking, right-click on the file and press the following menu item:


Be very considerate when you make this change. You might upset your fellow developers who pull your change.

@j6t: the mentioned files are the DLLs, which are the result of the build process of the solution. How could this upset anybody?

They generated their own build product, they committed it, now this change comes along and removes it without knowing about their updated version. That's a merge conflict. It's nothing spectacularly wrong (it's alright in fact), but if they aren't fluent in Git and there is no knowledgable person nearby, some may scratch their head about what's going on.

@j6t: thanks for the concern, but the actual situation is far more easy: the other developer has left the company and here in the company we never add our own binaries to our GIT repositories.
